# Repeat XSLT for unkown number of elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to change XML coming from web order softare, in order to map the data to a management software within our company. I've been successful with all of the header info, but now I'm at the point where I need to bring in the Line Item details. The amount of line items is depending on the order and always different. I need my XSLT to repeat until all line items are copied into the new XML file (I realize there's probably a better way to say that, but I'm not sure how to at the moment.)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<cXML version="1.2.005" xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="xx" timestamp="2023-04-07T09:12:23">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="DUNS">
        <Identity>1282</Identity>
      </Credential>
      <Credential domain="CompanyName">
        <Identity>xxxx</Identity>
      </Credential>
      <Credential domain="InteropKey">
        <Identity>xxxx</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="CompanyName">
        <Identity>xxxx</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <Credential domain="DUNS">
        <Identity>xxxx</Identity>
        <SharedSecret></SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
      <UserAgent>WildFire</UserAgent>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request deploymentMode="production">
    <OrderRequest>
      <OrderRequestHeader orderID="3035" orderDate="2023-04-07T09:12:23" type="new">
        <Total>
          <Money currency="USD">42.40</Money>
        </Total>
        <BillTo><Address addressID="xxxx">
          <Name xml:lang="en-US">Billing</Name>
          <PostalAddress name="">
            <DeliverTo>xxxx</DeliverTo>
            <Street>xxxx</Street>
            <Street></Street>   
            <City>xxxx</City>
            <State>xx</State>
            <PostalCode>xxxxx</PostalCode>
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">US</Country>
          </PostalAddress>
          <Email>xxxx@xxxx.com</Email>
           <Phone>
            <TelephoneNumber>
              <CountryCode isoCountryCode="" />
              <AreaOrCityCode />
              <Number></Number>
            </TelephoneNumber>
          </Phone>
</Address></BillTo>
        <Shipping>
          <Money currency="USD">0</Money>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">
          </Description>
        </Shipping>
        <Tax>
          <Money currency="USD">2.40</Money>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">
          </Description>
        </Tax>
        
        <Comments xml:lang="en-US">TEST YO</Comments>
          <Extrinsic name="UserName">xxxx</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="OrderFields"><Extrinsic name="Purchase Order Number:">5870010</Extrinsic></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="UserInteropID">xxxx</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="UserFirstName">xxxx</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="UserLastName">xxxx</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="UserPhone"></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="PaymentType">PurchaseOrder</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="PaymentSource"><Extrinsic name="PaymentType">PurchaseOrder</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="Amount">42.40</Extrinsic></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="BuyerInteropID">xxxx</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="BillingAddressInteropID"></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="OrderType">Standard</Extrinsic>
          
        <Extrinsic name="FromUserIP">xxxx</Extrinsic>
        
      </OrderRequestHeader>
      
    <ItemOut lineNumber="1" quantity="25" requestedDeliveryDate="">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>243-7</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>243-7</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
        </ItemID>
        <ItemDetail>
          <UnitPrice>
            <Money currency="USD">1.600000</Money>
          </UnitPrice>
          <Description xml:lang="en-US">xxxx</Description>
          <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
          <Classification domain=""></Classification>
          
          
          <Extrinsic name="lineItemID">xxxx</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="productType">Static</Extrinsic>
          
          <Extrinsic name="quantityMultiplier">1</Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="costCenter"></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="costCenterInteropID"></Extrinsic>    
          <Extrinsic name="ProductSpecs"><Extrinsic name="Trim Size">8.5"x11"</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="Print Type">4/4</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="Product Type">Static</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="Stored Jobs\">xxxx</Extrinsic><Extrinsic name="File Name">xxxx</Extrinsic></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="productInteropID"></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="variantInteropID"></Extrinsic>
          <Extrinsic name="shippingAddressInteropID"></Extrinsic>
          
            
            
          <Extrinsic name="shipWeight"></Extrinsic>
          
        <Extrinsic name="UserName">xxxx</Extrinsic></ItemDetail>
        <ShipTo><Address addressID="xxxx">
          <Name xml:lang="en-US">Address 1</Name>
          <PostalAddress name="">
            <DeliverTo> </DeliverTo>
            <Street>xxxx</Street>
            <Street></Street>   
            <City>xxxx</City>
            <State>PA</State>
            <PostalCode>17601</PostalCode>
            <Country isoCountryCode="US">US</Country>
          </PostalAddress>
          <Email></Email>
           <Phone>
            <TelephoneNumber>
              <CountryCode isoCountryCode="" />
              <AreaOrCityCode />
              <Number>7173687374</Number>
            </TelephoneNumber>
          </Phone>
</Address></ShipTo>
          
          
        
      </ItemOut></OrderRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Header">
<Header>
    <From>
        <Credential domain="DUNS">
            <Identity>
                <xsl:value-of select="From/Credential[@domain='DUNS']/Identity" />
            </Identity>
        </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
        <Credential domain="CompanyName">
            <Identity>
                <xsl:value-of select="To/Credential[@domain='CompanyName']/Identity" />
            </Identity>
        </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
        <Credential domain="DUNS">
            <Identity>
                <xsl:value-of select="Sender/Credential[@domain='DUNS']/Identity" />
            </Identity>
            <SharedSecret /> <!--what does this map to??-->
        </Credential>
    </Sender>
</Header>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Request">
<Request deploymentMode="production">
    <OrderRequest>
        <OrderRequestHeader>
            <xsl:attribute name="orderID">
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/@orderID" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="orderDate">
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/@orderDate" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/@type" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            
            <Total>
                <Money currency="USD">
                    <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Total/Money" />
                </Money>
            </Total>
            
            <!-- not currently used by Printers Plan<BillTo>
                <Address addressID="NotCurrentlyUsed">
                    <Name xml:lang="en-US">
                        <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/Name" />
                    </Name>
                    <PostalAddress>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/PostalAddress/@name" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <DeliverTo><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/DeliverTo" /></DeliverTo>
                        <Street><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/Street" /></Street>
                        <City><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/City" /></City>
                        <State><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/State" /></State>
                        <PostalCode><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/PostalCode" /></PostalCode>
                        <Country>
                            <xsl:attribute name="isoCountryCode">
                                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/Country/@isoCountryCode" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/BillTo/Address/PostalAddress/Country" />
                        </Country>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </BillTo>-->
            <!-- not currently used by Printers Plan<ShipTo>
                <Address addressID="NotCurrentlyUsed">
                    <Name xml:lang="en-US">
                        <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/Name" />
                    </Name>
                    <PostalAddress>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/PostalAddress/@name" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <DeliverTo><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/DeliverTo" /></DeliverTo>
                        <Street><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/Street" /></Street>
                        <City><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/City" /></City>
                        <State><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/State" /></State>
                        <PostalCode><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/PostalCode" /></PostalCode>
                        <Country>
                            <xsl:attribute name="isoCountryCode">
                                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/Country/@isoCountryCode" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/ShipTo/Address/PostalAddress/Country" />
                        </Country>
                    </PostalAddress>
                </Address>
            </ShipTo>-->
            <Shipping>
                <Money currency="USD"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Shipping/Money" /></Money>
                <Description xml:lang="en-US"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Shipping/Description" /></Description>
            </Shipping>
            <Tax>
                <Money currency="USD"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Tax/Money" /></Money>
                <Description xml:lang="en-US"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Tax/Description" /></Description>
            </Tax>
            <Contact>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='UserFirstName']" />&#160;<xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='UserLastName']" /></Name>
                <Email><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='UserName']" /></Email>
            </Contact>
            <Comments xml:lang="en-US">
                <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Comments" />
            </Comments>
            <Extrinsic name="JobTitle">
            
            </Extrinsic>
            <Extrinsic name="Purchase Order Number:">
             <xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Extrinsic[@name='OrderFields']/Extrinsic[@name='Purchase Order Number:']" />
            </Extrinsic>
            <!--where do this go?<Extrinsic name="YourFieldName2">
            
            </Extinsic>-->
        </OrderRequestHeader>
        <!-- Item out is harder to figure out - needs to be a copy so it brings all items in... or repeat until all items are in-->
        <ItemOut>
            <xsl:attribute name="lineNumber"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@lineNumber" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@quantity" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="requestedDeliveryDate"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@requestedDeliveryDate" /></xsl:attribute>
            
            <ItemID>
                <SupplierPartID><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemID/SupplierPartID" /></SupplierPartID>
            </ItemID>
        </ItemOut>
    </OrderRequest>
</Request>
</xsl:template>

 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need it to repeat that to bring in all of the  elements that may exist in the XML.
Also - I realize this is likely far from the most efficient way to do this. I'm learning as I go.
advice appreciated.

I  did try to add a <xsl:template match="ItemOut"> around the  element thinking that would reference all  elements in the XML regardless of their attributes but it failed because it's inside of the other template tag. Maybe there's a better way to avoid the other template so I can use it here?

UPDATE (THIS MAY BE ALL YOU NEED TO READ NOW):
xsl:for-each I think does what I need it to do as far as processing all of the  elements in the XML. Now, I'm having trouble getting the attribute values.
XML:

```
<ItemOut lineNumber="1" quantity="25" requestedDeliveryDate="">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>243-7</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>243-7</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
        </ItemID>
</ItemOut>
<ItemOut lineNumber="2" quantity="75" requestedDeliveryDate="">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>243-9</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>243-7</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
        </ItemID>
</ItemOut>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OrderRequest/ItemOut">
        <ItemOut>
            <xsl:attribute name="lineNumber"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@lineNumber" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@quantity" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="requestedDeliveryDate"><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/@requestedDeliveryDate" /></xsl:attribute>
            
            <ItemID>
                <SupplierPartID><xsl:value-of select="OrderRequest/ItemOut/ItemID/SupplierPartID" /></SupplierPartID>
            </ItemID>
        </ItemOut>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Intended Result:

```
<ItemOut lineNumber="1" quantity="25" requestedDeliveryDate="">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>243-7</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>243-7</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
        </ItemID>
</ItemOut>
<ItemOut lineNumber="2" quantity="75" requestedDeliveryDate="">
        <ItemID>
          <SupplierPartID>243-9</SupplierPartID>
          <SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>243-7</SupplierPartAuxiliaryID>
        </ItemID>
</ItemOut>
```

**I realize this result is exactly like the input... there are other elements I need to change that aren't showing here currently as I'm just looking for proof of concept at this point. Right now it's outputting both  elements with the attributes, but the attribute values are empty.**

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result. Reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also help greatly. -- Hint: use either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:appy-templates` to process an unknown number of elements.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I think xsl:for-each is exactly what I need. Need to figure out why it's not bringing the attribute values in now, but that brough in all <ItemOut> elements just like I need. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OrderRequest/ItemOut">
```

puts you in the context of `ItemOut`. From there, the path to the current element's attributes is just `@attribute-name`. Likewise for the descendant element `SupplierPartID`.

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OrderRequest/ItemOut">
    <ItemOut>
        <xsl:attribute name="lineNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="@lineNumber" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="quantity">
            <xsl:value-of select="@quantity" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="requestedDeliveryDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="@requestedDeliveryDate" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <ItemID>
            <SupplierPartID>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemID/SupplierPartID" />
            </SupplierPartID>
        </ItemID>
    </ItemOut>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or, if you prefer, take advantage of [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates) to shorten your code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OrderRequest/ItemOut">
    <ItemOut lineNumber="{@lineNumber}" quantity="{@quantity}" requestedDeliveryDate="{@requestedDeliveryDate}">
        <ItemID>
            <SupplierPartID>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemID/SupplierPartID" />
            </SupplierPartID>
        </ItemID>
    </ItemOut>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want a stylesheet which essentially makes a copy of your original (with some modifications) suggests to me that (as you suspected) you are indeed going about this the hard way.

In general, the best approach to writing a stylesheet to perform this kind of transformation is to make use of an ["identity template"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) which is a generic template which matches any item in the source document and copies it to the output, applying templates recursively to perform the same operation on the children of any matched element. This single template will copy your entire document, and crucially it does so in a way which allows you to easily override that simple copying behaviour in cases where you need to do something different.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- 
    TO DO: add other templates to make any desired modifications 
  -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you just need to create additional templates, each of which is responsible for handling one exception to that general rule; e.g. to ignore a certain element or attribute in the source document, or to insert some new content in some particular place, or to sort certain elements, etc.

In general, if the structure of your output document is supposed to closely reflect the structure of your source document, especially if that source document's structure might vary, then your stylesheet should rely on templates which use pattern-matching (rather than `xsl:for-each` loops), and in particular, if the output document is largely a copy of the input, then a single identity template will do the bulk of the stylesheet's work.

The stylesheet you've written has a style which is most appropriate for cases where the structure of your output document is predefined and fixed. In such cases, it's often appropriate for a stylesheet to have even just a single template that contains that entire structure of the output document, and which simply populates each part of it with the appropriate data drawn from the input document.